# problems reading a file

Tags: java, file, file-io

I'm trying to read this file:

> Distinguido/a cliente:
>
> Le damos la bienvenida a nuestra empresa y deseamos que nuestra
>   relación sea siempre muy satisfactoria.
>
> Muy atentamente,
>
> El director

and it's **obligatory** to do it as if the words in the file were "Paraula" objects.
This is the class Paraula:

```
public class Paraula {

    private static final int MAXIM = 900;
    public char[] lletres;
    public int longitud;
    public static boolean salto;

    /**
     * El constructor Paraula crea una objecte paraula de longitud 0 (buida)
     */
    public Paraula() {
        lletres = new char[MAXIM];
        longitud = 0;
    }

    /**
     * passa la paraula a cadena de caràcters
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
            s += lletres[i];
        }
        return s;
    }

    /**
     * Afegeix una lletra que es passa com a paràmetre a la paraula
     * @param c
     */
    public void afegirCaracter(char c) {
        if (longitud < MAXIM) {
            lletres[longitud] = c;
            longitud++;
        }
    }

    /**
     * compara l'objecte amb la paraula passada per paràmetre
     * i retorna vertader si són iguals. És la cerca d'un caràcter diferent
     * @param p
     * @return
     */
//    public boolean esIgualA(Paraula p) {
//        int i = 0;
//        while (lletres[i] == p.lletres[i] && i < longitud) {
//            i++;
//        }
//        return lletres[i] == p.lletres[i];
//    }
    public boolean esIgualA(Paraula b) {
        boolean iguals = longitud == b.longitud;
        for (int idx = 0; (idx < longitud) && iguals; idx++) {
            iguals = lletres[idx] == b.lletres[idx];
        }
        return iguals;
    }



    /**
     * retorna vertader si la parula té longitud zero
     * @return
     */
    public boolean buida() {
        return longitud == 0;
    }
}
```

And I have this class to read the files:

```
public class FicheroPalabraIn {

    private int x;
    private FileReader fin = null;
    public static boolean salto;

    /**
     * El constructor FitxerParaulaIn crida al constructor de FileReader i
     * llegeix fins al principi de la primera paraula si n'hi ha cap o fins al
     * final de fitxer en cas contrari
     *
     * @param nom
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public FicheroPalabraIn(String nom) throws Exception {
        fin = new FileReader(nom);
        x = fin.read();
        principiParaula();
    }

    /**
     * tanca el fitxer de caràcters
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void TancaFitxer() throws Exception {
        fin.close();
    }

    /**
     * El mètode llegir retorna una paraula del fitxer, per això cerca el final
     * de la paraula, en aquest cas s'ha suposat que no hi ha signes de
     * puntuació diferents de blanc i que la paraula mai serà més gran del
     * previst. El programa és una cerca del final de la paraula Després de
     * llegir la paraula ens posicionam al principi de la següent o al fi de
     * fitxer
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Paraula llegir() throws Exception {
        Paraula p = new Paraula();
        char c = (char) x;

        while ((c != ' ') && (c != '\n') && (c != '\r') && (x != -1)) {
            p.afegirCaracter(c);
            x = fin.read();
            c = (char) x;
        }
        principiParaula();

        return p;
    }

    public Paraula llegirCarta() throws Exception { //in this method I use a boolean to indicate when it reads a \n but it doesn't work as expected
        Paraula p = new Paraula();
        char c = (char) x;
        while (x != -1) {
            x = fin.read();
            c = (char) x;
            if ((c == '\n') || (c == '\r')) {
                salto = true;

            } else {
                p.afegirCaracter(c);
            }
        }
        principiParaula();
        return p;
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Paraula llegirNombre() throws Exception {
        Paraula p = new Paraula();
        char c = (char) x;

        while ((c != '#') && (x != -1)) {
            p.afegirCaracter(c);
            x = fin.read();
            c = (char) x;
        }
        principiParaula();

        return p;
    }

    public Paraula llegirDireccion() throws Exception {
        Paraula p = new Paraula();
        char c = (char) x;

        while ((x != -1) && (c != '\n') && (c != '\r')) {
            p.afegirCaracter(c);
            x = fin.read();
            c = (char) x;
        }
        principiParaula();

        return p;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //El mètode principiParaula és privat i és una cerca del principi de paraula
    private void principiParaula() throws Exception {
        char c = (char) x;
        while (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\r') {
            x = fin.read();
            c = (char) x;
        }
    }

    /**
     * El mètode quedenParaules retorna vertader si no s'està al fi de fitxer
     *
     * @return
     */
    public boolean QuedenParaules() {
        return x != -1;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need to read the file and then write the content in another file, but it doesn't read "\n" "\r" so when I write it the source file appears in the new file in just one line. How can I do it to make it "save" or know when the char read is a '\n' to write it in the new file and still using this method of reading as if the words were Paraula objects?

Thank you

Comment: I know it easier, but it's for university and it's obligatory to do it the way I explained @BooRadley

Comment: If due to some requirement you need to use that parser you can use the String `split()` function on your line endings to obtain an array of substrings.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will want to use the `readLine()` function from the `BufferedReader` class to parse the Strings line-by-line and create your Paraula object.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are initializing FicheroPalabraIn and then calling llegirCarta().

This method detects correctly \r and \n, but it doesn't store them in the object of type Paraula, only marks the static field salto as true.

If you want to store that chars, call in these cases to afegirCaracter().

On the other hand, the first char in the file isn't stored in this way, it's forgotten in the call to principiParaula()